# how to allow php .htacces to create folder for upload?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP app and trying to do this:

```
$newPath ='uploads/patients/'.$t;
$path = "../../".$newPath;
if (!file_exists($newPath)) {
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
```

I have this htaccess code:

---

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /aioshosp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

How do I allow it to make dir?

Comment: Is there an error message when doing `mkdir($path, 0777, true);`?

Answer (score 0):

Allowing directory creation is usually not a htaccess issue, but file system permissions.

Maybe you must set correct open_basedir directive:
    php_value open_basedir "/app/path"